# Unable to extract Objects from categories(Revit Types)?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm trying to extract all the Doors and select them in the Forge Api viewer using Javascript

```
viewer.search('door', function(id){console.log(id); 
viewer.isolate(IdsFromAbove); // Does not highlight the doors..
// Returns 72 objects and none seem to be doors
```

The code below highlights all the doors when I manually input the dbid and isolate it.

```
viewer.isolate(DoorCategoryDbId);
```

What would be a way I can actually select all the doors using Javascript like they do in the Model Browser extension ?
[Model Browser in forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPPbW.png)

Comment: Hi, if the given answer was not enough, ask doubts by commenting, in case your issue got resolved with the answer please accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewer.search('<property.value>', function(dbIds) {
        console.log(dbIds.length);
        getSubset(dbIds, property.name, property.value, function(dbIds) {
            oViewer.isolate(dbIds)
        })
    })
```

Blog Reference: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/property-based-selection-isolation